# Netherlands Medical Insurance

Tags: netherlands, health-insurance

I need a recommendation for a good medical insurance company in Netherlands (Eindhoven), I am expatriate and will stay in Netherlands for a year ?

Comment: Just use https://www.independer.nl/zorgverzekering/intro.aspx and do it in chrome with google translate extension

Comment: @EugenMartynov : There are translation extensions for other browsers, including Firefox.